# What is the best way to implement a "Find a Store" feature in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-maps, geolocation, postgis

I will be implementing a search feature on a project to allow a user to find the nearest store based on driving time given a input physical address. I would prefer showing a Google maps of the closest dealers. I am using PostgreSQL 8.4.x with Rails 2.1. Can anyone recommend a good solution (Ruby gem, Maps API such Google, [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) database, etc)? Thanks, Chirag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use Geokit:

https://github.com/andre/geokit-gem

Or Geokit Rails 3:

https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3

Then of course, I use my gem gmaps4rails

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really done anything like that before, but these resources should be quite useful :

http://ym4r.rubyforge.org/tutorial_ym4r_georuby.html

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Comment: BTW, just released a screencast for gmaps4rails: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg5-33zedqM (anothe coming soon)